# Trying to make a top navigation header?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a TOP Navigation header where I can put a LOGO and then a Drop down button with a profile image.

Heres What I'm trying to do. I already have my Side Navigation Made but cant for some reason figure out how to make the top navigation.

[image: What I'm trying to do.]

Here's my Current CSS for my Side Navigaiton:

```
.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
background:#e7e7e7;  /*Background color for the Side Navigation */
border-right:1px solid #e7e7e7;
position:absolute;
top: 10%; /* Edit the Height from the Header */
bottom:0;
height:100%;
left:0;


}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
 font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;

}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
overflow-y:auto;
overflow:visible;
}

a:hover,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#5fa2db;
}
.area {
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Here's my Current HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>TITLE </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet01.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
  <!---  <div class="navbar">
<img src="logo" alt="LOGO">

   </div>
            MAYBE HAVE A header? --->

    <div class="area"></div><nav class="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Dashboard
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            UI Components
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Forms
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Pages
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Graphs and Statistics
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Typography and Icons
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Tables
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Maps
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Documentation
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="logout">
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                         <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Logout
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Any idea how I might be able to do this?

Comment: do you consider of using bootstrap?

Comment: I could use boostrap. How would I go about making the TOP navigation with my Side Navigation in boostrap?

Comment: I'll try to integrate boostraps V.4 Nav Bar into my design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve what you are after. I find using a fixed navigation is great because that way the user always has access to the site menu even when scrolling on long pages.

The markup would go something like...

Logo here

```
<nav class="site-header__nav-container">
    <ul class="site-header__nav">
        <li>Menu
            <ul class="site-header__nav-menu">
                <li>Menu item 1</li>
                <li>Menu item 2</li>
                <li>Menu item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The css/scss would go something like...

```
    $header-height: 80px;

.site-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #999;
    height: $header-height;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 50;

    &__nav {
        position: relative;

        &:hover ul {
            max-height: 100vh;
            visibility: visible;
        }

    }

    &__nav-menu {
        max-height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;

    }

}

body {
    margin-top: $header-height + 20px;
}
```

You can check a codepen here -- https://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/RLZxeV

I have used a fixed height for the header, and used the same value for the top margin on the body tag, that way you don't cut off any content from your page.

I have used flex to position the items of the header because flex is awesome! You could use other positioning techniques, or if you are using a css framework like bootstrap, then you can use specific class names for positioning.

Hope this helps!